# FDR q-values interpretation

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate

In performing 43 test on two groups of individuals (independent t-test) I obtained 27 significant results, then adjusting the pvalues with BH procedure for controlling FDR I obtained the so-called q-values. There are 14 variables which have a q-value less than .05. I understand that a q-value might be described as the probability of obtaining a false positive for that particular test, i.e. if for a specific test I have a q-value of 0.03 then there is a 3% chance that the test is actually a false positive (very unlikely).
What I still struggle to get is how to report my results, as usually q-values are reported as adjusted p-values and the corresponding test deemed to be significant or not, but I find this might be wrong or confusing, since q-values represent the estimated proportion of false positives.